# Enum.valueOf in Kotlin

Tags: java, enums, kotlin

Is there a way to make something like this work in Kotlin without the reflection?

```
inline fun <reified T : kotlin.Enum<T>> safeValueOf(type: String?): T? {
    return java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, type)
}
```

The example below doesn't compile due to:

> Type parameter bound for T in `inline fun <reified T : kotlin.Enum<T>> safeValueOf(type: kotlin.String?): T?`
>   is not satisfied: inferred type `TestEnum?` is not a subtype of `kotlin.Enum<TestEnum?>`

```
enum class TestEnum

fun main() {
    val value: TestEnum? = safeValueOf("test")
}
```

Comment: Your function works if you specify the type parameter value explicitly: `val value = safeValueOf<TestEnum>("test")`

Comment: Why not just use Kotlin implementation of [`valueOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants)?

Comment: @yole thanks, that's it. Do you mind posting this as the answer?

Comment: @soon I would like to extend the functionality of `valueOf` and use it with different enum types

Comment: Can I ask how this is safeValueOf? this can still throw exceptions

Comment: @charlie_pl the question title doesn't really say anything about safety. The problem at that time was making this construct work, and, as you've correctly noted, the `safeValueOf` is not safe here as it's just a minimal example of the issue at hand. But you can easily imagine how it can be made safe from here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your function works if you specify the type parameter value explicitly:

```
val value = safeValueOf<TestEnum>("test")
```

The original code is supposed to work as well, but doesn't work because of a bug in the type inference implementation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11218

Answer (score 19):

### Crash-safe Solution

Create an extension and then call `valueOf<MyEnum>("value")`. If the type is invalid, you'll get null and have to handle it

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> valueOf(type: String): T? {
    return try {
        java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, type)
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        null
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set a default value, calling `valueOf<MyEnum>("value", MyEnum.FALLBACK)`, and avoiding a null response. You can extend your specific enum to have the default be automatic

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> valueOf(type: String, default: T): T {
    return try {
        java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, type)
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        default
    }
}
```

Or if you want both, make the second:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> valueOf(type: String, default: T): T = valueOf<T>(type) ?: default
```

Answer (score 18):

I would typically add something like this to enum:

```
companion object {
    fun from(type: String?): TestEnum = values().find { it.name == type } ?: DEFAULT
}
```

this would make a clean call

```
val value = TestEnum.from("test")
```

of course you can make it return null

Answer (score 6):

> Since Kotlin 1.1, it's possible to access the constants in an enum class in a generic way, using the enumValues() and enumValueOf() functions:

```
enum class RGB { RED, GREEN, BLUE }

inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> printAllValues() {
    print(enumValues<T>().joinToString { it.name })
}

printAllValues<RGB>() // prints RED, GREEN, BLUE
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants